# Window authentication doesn't work for specified groups after reinstalling IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5, windows-authentication

After reinstalling IIS 7.5 windows authentication doesn't work for specifies user groups. All that groups are visible in IIS. Windows authentication is enabled, Anonymous authentication is Enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permisstion of those was removed automatically.
Set all permisstions to those grups all work fine.